# Material React Table filtering should have multi-select and filter based on a text search per column

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-react-table

In the below image, there is a multi-select option for **state** column, what's the way to have both search and multi-select option for filtering the **state** column. Currently the **filterVariant** property is accepting either "multi-select" or "text". How to get both text and multi-select together for filtering the state column

[Material react table with multi-select variant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvqbc.jpg)

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { MaterialReactTable } from 'material-react-table';
import { citiesList, data, usStateList } from './makeData';

const Example = () => {
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        header: 'Status',
        accessorFn: (originalRow) => (originalRow.isActive ? 'true' : 'false'), //must be strings
        id: 'isActive',
        filterVariant: 'checkbox',
        Cell: ({ cell }) =>
          cell.getValue() === 'true' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive',
        size: 170,
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'name',
        header: 'Name',
        filterVariant: 'text', // default
        size: 100,
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'age',
        header: 'Age',
        filterVariant: 'range',
        filterFn: 'between',
        size: 80,
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'salary',
        header: 'Salary',
        Cell: ({ cell }) =>
          cell.getValue().toLocaleString('en-US', {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'USD',
          }),
        filterVariant: 'range-slider',
        filterFn: 'betweenInclusive', // default (or between)
        muiTableHeadCellFilterSliderProps: {
          marks: true,
          max: 200_000, //custom max (as opposed to faceted max)
          min: 30_000, //custom min (as opposed to faceted min)
          step: 10_000,
          valueLabelFormat: (value) =>
            value.toLocaleString('en-US', {
              style: 'currency',
              currency: 'USD',
            }),
        },
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'city',
        header: 'City',
        filterVariant: 'select',
        filterSelectOptions: citiesList, //custom options list (as opposed to faceted list)
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'state',
        header: 'State',
        filterVariant: 'multi-select',
        filterSelectOptions: usStateList, //custom options list (as opposed to faceted list)
      },
    ],
    [],
  );

  return (
    <MaterialReactTable
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      initialState={{ showColumnFilters: true }}
    />
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Could anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance

I tried with using an array for the filterVariant but its not supported. So seeking for a solution from the community, to have both text and multi-select together. Thanks in advance